# Combine 2 UIImage views with zoom and offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

thanks for reading.

I have a background image and a foreground image. The foreground image is in a UIScrollView so can be resized and repositioned over the background image. The background image is set as Aspect Fit. I have a function that combines the two UIImages into a new UIImage. That works fine, but what I can't get right is the x,y co-ordinates of one view over the other.

Here's some code:

```
CGFloat bgImageScale = self.backgroundImageView.bounds.size.height / self.bgImage.size.height; // Gives me the AspectFit scale.
CGFloat bgOffsetX = (self.backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width - self.bgImage.size.width * bgImageScale) / 2.0;
CGFloat bgOffsetY = 0.0;
CGFloat fgImageScale = self.fgImageScrollView.zoomScale;
CGFloat fgOffsetX = -self.fgImageScrollView.contentOffset.x;
CGFloat fgOffsetY = -self.fgImageScrollView.contentOffset.y;

CGPoint imageOffset = CGPointMake((fgOffsetX - bgOffsetX) * bgImageScale, (fgOffsetY - bgOffsetY) * bgImageScale);


[self.delegate completedOverlayImage:
  [self mergeImage:self.fgImage
         withImage:self.bgImage
        usingAlpha:0.5f
        withOffset:imageOffset
          andScale:fgImageScale / bgImageScale
]];
```

In brief, the compeletedOverlayImage code does the following relevant bit:

```
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
[topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(imageOffset.x, imageOffset.y, newSize.width*imageScale, newSize.height*imageScale) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];
```

So I just can't get the imageOffset stuff right to get the new image overlaid the same as it appeared on-screen.

By the way, this app is iOS 7 and up only.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `UIView` `convertRect:toView:` method.

Assuming that your view hierarchy looks like this

```
SomeViewController
   View               // the view controller's main view
      BgView          // the background view (UIImageView)
      ScrollView      
         FgView       // the foreground view (UIImageView)
```

If the foreground image is a UIImageView that's a child of the scroll view, then you can convert the `FgView` frame coordinates to the main view coordinate system with a line of code like this

```
CGRect foregroundFrame = [self.foregroundImageView convertRect:self.foregroundImageView.bounds toView:self.view];
```

Since the BgView's frame is already in mainView coordinates, this will give you both frames in the same coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, that's the right view hierarchy. Good idea with convertRect, however the ScrollView and BgView are both in the same coordinate system, so using convertRect or using contentOffset of the ScrollView both provide the same number.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it myself. So for anyone else attempting the same thing, here's the code:

```
CGFloat bgImageScale = self.backgroundImageView.bounds.size.height / self.bgImage.size.height;
CGFloat bgOffsetX = (self.backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width - self.bgImage.size.width * bgImageScale) / 2.0;
CGFloat bgOffsetY = 0.0;
CGFloat fgImageScale = self.fgImageScrollView.zoomScale;
CGFloat fgRelativeZoom = fgImageScale / bgImageScale; // How much is fg zoomed compared to bg?
CGFloat fgOffsetX = -self.fgImageScrollView.contentOffset.x; // We want the offset of the (0,0), not the offset of the viewport. Hence, negative.
CGFloat fgOffsetY = -self.fgImageScrollView.contentOffset.y;

CGPoint imageOffset = CGPointMake(fgOffsetX / bgImageScale - bgOffsetX, fgOffsetY / bgImageScale - bgOffsetY);

[self.delegate completedOverlayImage:
 [self mergeImage:self.fgImage
        withImage:self.bgImage
       usingAlpha:0.5f
       withOffset:imageOffset
         andScale:fgRelativeZoom
]];
```

and the function to combine the images (assuming iOS 7 which lets you set scale to zero in the UIGraphicsBeginContextWithOptions() call):

```
- (UIImage*) mergeImage:(UIImage*)topImage withImage:(UIImage*)bottomImage usingAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha withOffset:(CGPoint)imageOffset andScale:(CGFloat)imageScale {

    int width = bottomImage.size.width;
    int height = bottomImage.size.height;

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    [topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(imageOffset.x, imageOffset.y, newSize.width*imageScale, newSize.height*imageScale) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Hope that helps someone else out there.